# RequireJS load main module in a top level directory from a subdirectory

Tags: javascript, requirejs

How can i `require` the common module using inline call from a subdirectory? My main module is in a one optimized script along with `requirejs` which is loaded as the first script in the page. It has an absolute url to the root `js` directory.

Now, on a page which is at the URL `localhost/myproject/checkout/cart`, i am trying to load the cart module using:

```
require(['common/main'],function(common){
    require(['app/cart']);
});
```

But it is trying to reference `localhost/myproject/checkout/cart/js/app/cart.js` which it will never find. The `baseUrl` is set to `./js`.

What am i doing wrong here?

`common/main.js` is as :

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: './js',
    paths: {
        app: 'app',
        ... // More code
    }
});
```

Please i need help with relative url paths in requireJS.

Comment: Well what's the real path to the cart.js file?

Comment: @Juhana the real path is localhost/myproject/js/app/cart.js

Answer (score 0):

Config is relative to URL. When URL is `localhost/myproject/checkout/cart`, then path to `app/cart` is:

```
URL + baseUrl + module + '.js'
localhost/myproject/checkout/cart/js/app/cart.js
```

In this case set `baseUrl` to `../../js/`